# JQuery autocomplete json parse error

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I try to use JQuery autocomplete and I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
```

My code is like this, the HTML:

```
<div id="fastSearchBox" class="fastSearchBox">
            <span style="direction: rtl; float: right;">search</span>
            <input id="fastSearchInput" type="text" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;"></input>
        </div>
```

The javascript:

```
users = [{"data":1,"value":"foo"}];

                    $("#fastSearchInput").autocomplete({   
                    source: users,
                    select: function (event, ui)
                    {

                    }});
```

I have no idea why but changing `source`to `lookup` made it works

Comment: this issue is familiar to me, are you sure you're not using some php within your code somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I think maybe the source is not good

Comment: Change to "lookup" and in your json check that their is no empty values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

The autocomplete expects an array in the above format. Change your array to the following:

```
<body>
    <div id="fastSearchBox" class="fastSearchBox">
    <span style="direction: rtl; float: right;">search</span>
    <input id="fastSearchInput" type="text" style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px;">
    </div>
</body>

var users = [ 
    {data: 1, value: "foo" },
    {data: 2, value: "foo2" },
    {data: 3, value: "foo3" }
];

$( "#fastSearchInput").autocomplete({
    source: users
});

$( "#fastSearchInput").on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
    alert(ui.item.data);
});
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle link with working code. https://jsfiddle.net/9roepp5z/1/

You can use the structure you had, but the drop down uses your data column for the display and the value column for what it places into the textbox upon selection. You did have an unnecessary closing INPUT tag.